# Как в инпут запихнуть 2 img. При этом на Input:focus одно из изображений(refresh) должно исчезать

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался сделать фокус через внешний див, но нужно конкретно исчезновение при фокусе на инпут

```css
.intup_container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 1%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 97%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.formInput {
  width: 85%;
  margin: 0 7px 0 5px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-image: url("images/search.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

.intup_container:focus .vanish {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="intup_container" tabindex="0">
    <input class="formInput" type='text' placeholder="Search">
    <img class="vanish" src="images/refresh.svg" alt="refresh">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Объясните подробнее, что Вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: Почему-то не отображает картинку, но попробую дать её ссылкой 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fscb.png

Comment: Не могу понять, чего хочет автор, напишите более внятный вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой вариант:

```css
.search-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.search-input > img {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.search-input > input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: calc(20px + 5px + 20px + 10px + 5px);
}

.search-input #search {
  right: calc(20px + 5px + 10px); /* ширина картинки + отступ */
}

.search-input #refresh {
  right: 10px;
}

.search-input > input:focus {
  padding-right: calc(20px + 10px + 5px);
}

.search-input > input:focus ~ #search {
  right: 10px;
}

.search-input > input:focus ~ #refresh {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-input">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Поиск">
  <img id="search" src="https://i.imgur.com/9y3f0Ou.png">
  <img id="refresh" src="https://i.imgur.com/2QpjHPH.png">
</div>
```

С анимацией

```css
.search-input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.search-input > img {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.search-input > input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: calc(20px + 5px + 20px + 10px + 5px);
}

.search-input #search {
  right: calc(20px + 5px + 10px); /* ширина картинки + отступ */
}

.search-input #refresh {
  right: 10px;
}

.search-input > input:focus {
  padding-right: calc(20px + 10px + 5px);
}

.search-input > input:focus ~ #search {
  right: 10px;
}

.search-input > input:focus ~ #refresh {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.search-input > input {
  transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.search-input > img {
  transition: all .15s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-input">
  <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Поиск">
  <img id="search" src="https://i.imgur.com/9y3f0Ou.png">
  <img id="refresh" src="https://i.imgur.com/2QpjHPH.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что нужно

Answer (score 2):

*Пример скрытия последней иконки*

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
}

input {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ico {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.item input:focus~.ref {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
<g fill="#000" stroke="none" id="refresh">
  <path d="M433.109,23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948,0-9.226,1.812-12.847,5.424l-37.113,36.835
   c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091,5.283,247.056,0.003,219.266,0.003c-52.344,0-98.022,15.843-137.042,47.536
   C43.203,79.228,17.509,120.574,5.137,171.587v1.997c0,2.474,0.903,4.617,2.712,6.423c1.809,1.809,3.949,2.712,6.423,2.712h56.814
   c4.189,0,7.042-2.19,8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032,13.035-30.166,15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698,31.023-38.734,53.103-51.106
   c22.082-12.371,45.873-18.559,71.376-18.559c38.261,0,71.473,13.039,99.645,39.115l-39.406,39.397
   c-3.607,3.617-5.421,7.902-5.421,12.851c0,4.948,1.813,9.231,5.421,12.847c3.621,3.617,7.905,5.424,12.854,5.424h127.906
   c4.949,0,9.233-1.807,12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616,5.42-7.898,5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529,31.593,436.733,27.312,433.109,23.694z"/>
  <path d="M422.253,255.813h-54.816c-4.188,0-7.043,2.187-8.562,6.566c-7.99,19.034-13.038,30.163-15.129,33.4
   c-13.326,21.693-31.028,38.735-53.102,51.106c-22.083,12.375-45.874,18.556-71.378,18.556c-18.461,0-36.259-3.423-53.387-10.273
   c-17.13-6.858-32.454-16.567-45.966-29.13l39.115-39.112c3.615-3.613,5.424-7.901,5.424-12.847c0-4.948-1.809-9.236-5.424-12.847
   c-3.617-3.62-7.898-5.431-12.847-5.431H18.274c-4.952,0-9.235,1.811-12.851,5.431C1.807,264.844,0,269.132,0,274.08v127.907
   c0,4.945,1.807,9.232,5.424,12.847c3.619,3.61,7.902,5.428,12.851,5.428c4.948,0,9.229-1.817,12.847-5.428l36.829-36.833
   c20.367,19.41,43.542,34.355,69.523,44.823c25.981,10.472,52.866,15.701,80.653,15.701c52.155,0,97.643-15.845,136.471-47.534
   c38.828-31.688,64.333-73.042,76.52-124.05c0.191-0.38,0.281-1.047,0.281-1.995c0-2.478-0.907-4.612-2.715-6.427
   C426.874,256.72,424.731,255.813,422.253,255.813z"/>
 </g>
<g id="surface">
<path d="M 482.257812 178.226562 L 10.484375 178.226562 L 10.484375 450.804688 L 639.515625 450.804688 L 639.515625 178.226562 Z M 251.613281 398.386719 L 209.675781 398.386719 L 209.675781 230.644531 L 209.675781 398.386719 Z M 366.933594 398.386719 L 366.933594 230.644531 L 325 314.515625 L 283.0625 230.644531 L 325 314.515625 L 366.933594 230.644531 Z M 482.257812 272.582031 L 482.257812 251.613281 C 482.257812 240.035156 472.867188 230.644531 461.289062 230.644531 L 419.355469 230.644531 C 407.773438 230.644531 398.386719 240.035156 398.386719 251.613281 L 398.386719 377.417969 C 398.386719 389 407.773438 398.386719 419.355469 398.386719 L 461.289062 398.386719 C 472.867188 398.386719 482.257812 389 482.257812 377.417969 L 482.257812 314.515625 L 482.257812 377.417969 C 482.257812 389 472.867188 398.386719 461.289062 398.386719 L 419.355469 398.386719 C 407.773438 398.386719 398.386719 389 398.386719 377.417969 L 398.386719 251.613281 C 398.386719 240.035156 407.773438 230.644531 419.355469 230.644531 L 461.289062 230.644531 C 472.867188 230.644531 482.257812 240.035156 482.257812 251.613281 Z M 482.257812 272.582031 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(74.509804%,54.509804%,86.27451%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 167.742188 450.804688 L 482.257812 450.804688 L 482.257812 503.226562 L 167.742188 503.226562 Z M 167.742188 450.804688 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(91.372549%,84.705882%,95.294118%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 167.742188 125.804688 L 482.257812 125.804688 L 482.257812 178.226562 L 167.742188 178.226562 Z M 167.742188 125.804688 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(91.372549%,84.705882%,95.294118%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 209.675781 83.871094 L 440.320312 83.871094 L 440.320312 104.839844 L 209.675781 104.839844 Z M 209.675781 83.871094 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 241.128906 52.417969 L 408.871094 52.417969 L 408.871094 73.386719 L 241.128906 73.386719 Z M 241.128906 52.417969 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 209.675781 524.195312 L 440.320312 524.195312 L 440.320312 545.160156 L 209.675781 545.160156 Z M 209.675781 524.195312 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 241.128906 555.644531 L 408.871094 555.644531 L 408.871094 576.613281 L 241.128906 576.613281 Z M 241.128906 555.644531 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 649.820312 177.34375 C 649.757812 176.632812 649.613281 175.929688 649.402344 175.25 C 649.230469 174.617188 648.992188 174.007812 648.699219 173.425781 C 648.402344 172.855469 648.050781 172.316406 647.652344 171.808594 C 647.210938 171.246094 646.714844 170.726562 646.175781 170.257812 C 645.933594 170.070312 645.808594 169.796875 645.554688 169.617188 L 545.160156 99.375 L 545.160156 10.484375 C 545.160156 4.695312 540.464844 0 534.675781 0 L 115.320312 0 C 109.53125 0 104.839844 4.695312 104.839844 10.484375 L 104.839844 99.378906 L 4.476562 169.617188 C 4.222656 169.796875 4.097656 170.070312 3.855469 170.257812 C 3.316406 170.726562 2.820312 171.25 2.378906 171.808594 C 1.980469 172.316406 1.628906 172.855469 1.332031 173.425781 C 1.035156 174.007812 0.800781 174.621094 0.628906 175.25 C 0.414062 175.929688 0.273438 176.632812 0.210938 177.347656 C 0.125 177.636719 0.0546875 177.929688 0 178.226562 L 0 450.804688 C 0 456.597656 4.695312 461.289062 10.484375 461.289062 L 104.839844 461.289062 L 104.839844 618.546875 C 104.839844 624.339844 109.53125 629.03125 115.324219 629.03125 L 534.679688 629.03125 C 540.46875 629.03125 545.160156 624.339844 545.160156 618.546875 L 545.160156 461.289062 L 639.515625 461.289062 C 645.308594 461.289062 650 456.597656 650 450.804688 L 650 178.226562 C 649.957031 177.929688 649.894531 177.636719 649.820312 177.34375 Z M 606.261719 167.742188 L 545.160156 167.742188 L 545.160156 124.976562 Z M 524.191406 20.96875 L 524.191406 167.742188 L 492.742188 167.742188 L 492.742188 125.804688 C 492.742188 120.015625 488.046875 115.324219 482.257812 115.324219 L 167.742188 115.324219 C 161.949219 115.324219 157.257812 120.015625 157.257812 125.804688 L 157.257812 167.742188 L 125.804688 167.742188 L 125.804688 20.96875 Z M 178.226562 167.742188 L 178.226562 136.289062 L 471.773438 136.289062 L 471.773438 167.742188 Z M 104.839844 167.742188 L 43.738281 167.742188 L 104.839844 124.976562 Z M 524.191406 608.066406 L 125.804688 608.066406 L 125.804688 461.289062 L 157.257812 461.289062 L 157.257812 503.226562 C 157.257812 509.015625 161.949219 513.710938 167.742188 513.710938 L 482.257812 513.710938 C 488.046875 513.710938 492.742188 509.015625 492.742188 503.226562 L 492.742188 461.289062 L 524.191406 461.289062 Z M 471.773438 461.289062 L 471.773438 492.742188 L 178.226562 492.742188 L 178.226562 461.289062 Z M 629.03125 440.324219 L 20.96875 440.324219 L 20.96875 188.710938 L 629.03125 188.710938 Z M 629.03125 440.324219 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 251.613281 241.128906 C 257.402344 241.128906 262.097656 236.433594 262.097656 230.644531 C 262.097656 224.855469 257.402344 220.160156 251.613281 220.160156 L 167.742188 220.160156 C 161.949219 220.160156 157.257812 224.855469 157.257812 230.644531 C 157.257812 236.433594 161.949219 241.128906 167.742188 241.128906 L 199.191406 241.128906 L 199.191406 387.902344 L 167.742188 387.902344 C 161.949219 387.902344 157.257812 392.597656 157.257812 398.386719 C 157.257812 404.175781 161.949219 408.871094 167.742188 408.871094 L 251.613281 408.871094 C 257.402344 408.871094 262.097656 404.175781 262.097656 398.386719 C 262.097656 392.597656 257.402344 387.902344 251.613281 387.902344 L 220.160156 387.902344 L 220.160156 241.128906 Z M 251.613281 241.128906 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 369.347656 220.445312 C 364.609375 219.324219 359.726562 221.605469 357.550781 225.960938 L 325 291.074219 L 292.5 225.960938 C 289.976562 220.75 283.707031 218.570312 278.492188 221.089844 C 274.839844 222.863281 272.535156 226.582031 272.578125 230.644531 L 272.578125 398.386719 C 272.578125 404.175781 277.273438 408.871094 283.0625 408.871094 C 288.851562 408.871094 293.546875 404.175781 293.546875 398.386719 L 293.546875 275.054688 L 315.617188 319.203125 C 318.707031 324.386719 325.410156 326.082031 330.59375 322.992188 C 332.152344 322.0625 333.453125 320.761719 334.382812 319.203125 L 356.449219 275.054688 L 356.449219 398.386719 C 356.449219 404.175781 361.144531 408.871094 366.933594 408.871094 C 372.726562 408.871094 377.417969 404.175781 377.417969 398.386719 L 377.417969 230.644531 C 377.417969 225.785156 374.074219 221.5625 369.347656 220.445312 Z M 369.347656 220.445312 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 461.289062 220.160156 L 419.355469 220.160156 C 401.984375 220.160156 387.902344 234.242188 387.902344 251.613281 L 387.902344 377.417969 C 387.902344 394.789062 401.984375 408.871094 419.355469 408.871094 L 461.289062 408.871094 C 478.660156 408.871094 492.742188 394.789062 492.742188 377.417969 L 492.742188 314.515625 C 492.742188 308.726562 488.046875 304.03125 482.257812 304.03125 L 440.320312 304.03125 C 434.53125 304.03125 429.839844 308.726562 429.839844 314.515625 C 429.839844 320.304688 434.53125 325 440.320312 325 L 471.773438 325 L 471.773438 377.417969 C 471.773438 383.210938 467.078125 387.902344 461.289062 387.902344 L 419.355469 387.902344 C 413.566406 387.902344 408.871094 383.210938 408.871094 377.417969 L 408.871094 251.613281 C 408.871094 245.824219 413.566406 241.128906 419.355469 241.128906 L 461.289062 241.128906 C 467.078125 241.128906 471.773438 245.824219 471.773438 251.613281 L 471.773438 272.582031 C 471.773438 278.371094 476.46875 283.066406 482.257812 283.066406 C 488.046875 283.066406 492.742188 278.371094 492.742188 272.582031 L 492.742188 251.613281 C 492.742188 234.242188 478.660156 220.160156 461.289062 220.160156 Z M 461.289062 220.160156 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
</g>
</svg>



<div class="item" tabindex="1">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 650 650" width="16" height="16" class="ico">
    <use xlink:href="#surface" x="0" />
  </svg>
  <input type="text">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 438 438" width="16" height="16" class="ico ref">
    <use xlink:href="#refresh" x="0" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

*Второй пример на случай если надо скрыть первую иконку*

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ico {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.item input:focus~.ref {
  display: none;
}

.ref {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
<g fill="#000" stroke="none" id="refresh">
  <path d="M433.109,23.694c-3.614-3.612-7.898-5.424-12.848-5.424c-4.948,0-9.226,1.812-12.847,5.424l-37.113,36.835
   c-20.365-19.226-43.684-34.123-69.948-44.684C274.091,5.283,247.056,0.003,219.266,0.003c-52.344,0-98.022,15.843-137.042,47.536
   C43.203,79.228,17.509,120.574,5.137,171.587v1.997c0,2.474,0.903,4.617,2.712,6.423c1.809,1.809,3.949,2.712,6.423,2.712h56.814
   c4.189,0,7.042-2.19,8.566-6.565c7.993-19.032,13.035-30.166,15.131-33.403c13.322-21.698,31.023-38.734,53.103-51.106
   c22.082-12.371,45.873-18.559,71.376-18.559c38.261,0,71.473,13.039,99.645,39.115l-39.406,39.397
   c-3.607,3.617-5.421,7.902-5.421,12.851c0,4.948,1.813,9.231,5.421,12.847c3.621,3.617,7.905,5.424,12.854,5.424h127.906
   c4.949,0,9.233-1.807,12.848-5.424c3.613-3.616,5.42-7.898,5.42-12.847V36.542C438.529,31.593,436.733,27.312,433.109,23.694z"/>
  <path d="M422.253,255.813h-54.816c-4.188,0-7.043,2.187-8.562,6.566c-7.99,19.034-13.038,30.163-15.129,33.4
   c-13.326,21.693-31.028,38.735-53.102,51.106c-22.083,12.375-45.874,18.556-71.378,18.556c-18.461,0-36.259-3.423-53.387-10.273
   c-17.13-6.858-32.454-16.567-45.966-29.13l39.115-39.112c3.615-3.613,5.424-7.901,5.424-12.847c0-4.948-1.809-9.236-5.424-12.847
   c-3.617-3.62-7.898-5.431-12.847-5.431H18.274c-4.952,0-9.235,1.811-12.851,5.431C1.807,264.844,0,269.132,0,274.08v127.907
   c0,4.945,1.807,9.232,5.424,12.847c3.619,3.61,7.902,5.428,12.851,5.428c4.948,0,9.229-1.817,12.847-5.428l36.829-36.833
   c20.367,19.41,43.542,34.355,69.523,44.823c25.981,10.472,52.866,15.701,80.653,15.701c52.155,0,97.643-15.845,136.471-47.534
   c38.828-31.688,64.333-73.042,76.52-124.05c0.191-0.38,0.281-1.047,0.281-1.995c0-2.478-0.907-4.612-2.715-6.427
   C426.874,256.72,424.731,255.813,422.253,255.813z"/>
 </g>
<g id="surface">
<path d="M 482.257812 178.226562 L 10.484375 178.226562 L 10.484375 450.804688 L 639.515625 450.804688 L 639.515625 178.226562 Z M 251.613281 398.386719 L 209.675781 398.386719 L 209.675781 230.644531 L 209.675781 398.386719 Z M 366.933594 398.386719 L 366.933594 230.644531 L 325 314.515625 L 283.0625 230.644531 L 325 314.515625 L 366.933594 230.644531 Z M 482.257812 272.582031 L 482.257812 251.613281 C 482.257812 240.035156 472.867188 230.644531 461.289062 230.644531 L 419.355469 230.644531 C 407.773438 230.644531 398.386719 240.035156 398.386719 251.613281 L 398.386719 377.417969 C 398.386719 389 407.773438 398.386719 419.355469 398.386719 L 461.289062 398.386719 C 472.867188 398.386719 482.257812 389 482.257812 377.417969 L 482.257812 314.515625 L 482.257812 377.417969 C 482.257812 389 472.867188 398.386719 461.289062 398.386719 L 419.355469 398.386719 C 407.773438 398.386719 398.386719 389 398.386719 377.417969 L 398.386719 251.613281 C 398.386719 240.035156 407.773438 230.644531 419.355469 230.644531 L 461.289062 230.644531 C 472.867188 230.644531 482.257812 240.035156 482.257812 251.613281 Z M 482.257812 272.582031 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(74.509804%,54.509804%,86.27451%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 167.742188 450.804688 L 482.257812 450.804688 L 482.257812 503.226562 L 167.742188 503.226562 Z M 167.742188 450.804688 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(91.372549%,84.705882%,95.294118%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 167.742188 125.804688 L 482.257812 125.804688 L 482.257812 178.226562 L 167.742188 178.226562 Z M 167.742188 125.804688 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(91.372549%,84.705882%,95.294118%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 209.675781 83.871094 L 440.320312 83.871094 L 440.320312 104.839844 L 209.675781 104.839844 Z M 209.675781 83.871094 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 241.128906 52.417969 L 408.871094 52.417969 L 408.871094 73.386719 L 241.128906 73.386719 Z M 241.128906 52.417969 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 209.675781 524.195312 L 440.320312 524.195312 L 440.320312 545.160156 L 209.675781 545.160156 Z M 209.675781 524.195312 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 241.128906 555.644531 L 408.871094 555.644531 L 408.871094 576.613281 L 241.128906 576.613281 Z M 241.128906 555.644531 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 649.820312 177.34375 C 649.757812 176.632812 649.613281 175.929688 649.402344 175.25 C 649.230469 174.617188 648.992188 174.007812 648.699219 173.425781 C 648.402344 172.855469 648.050781 172.316406 647.652344 171.808594 C 647.210938 171.246094 646.714844 170.726562 646.175781 170.257812 C 645.933594 170.070312 645.808594 169.796875 645.554688 169.617188 L 545.160156 99.375 L 545.160156 10.484375 C 545.160156 4.695312 540.464844 0 534.675781 0 L 115.320312 0 C 109.53125 0 104.839844 4.695312 104.839844 10.484375 L 104.839844 99.378906 L 4.476562 169.617188 C 4.222656 169.796875 4.097656 170.070312 3.855469 170.257812 C 3.316406 170.726562 2.820312 171.25 2.378906 171.808594 C 1.980469 172.316406 1.628906 172.855469 1.332031 173.425781 C 1.035156 174.007812 0.800781 174.621094 0.628906 175.25 C 0.414062 175.929688 0.273438 176.632812 0.210938 177.347656 C 0.125 177.636719 0.0546875 177.929688 0 178.226562 L 0 450.804688 C 0 456.597656 4.695312 461.289062 10.484375 461.289062 L 104.839844 461.289062 L 104.839844 618.546875 C 104.839844 624.339844 109.53125 629.03125 115.324219 629.03125 L 534.679688 629.03125 C 540.46875 629.03125 545.160156 624.339844 545.160156 618.546875 L 545.160156 461.289062 L 639.515625 461.289062 C 645.308594 461.289062 650 456.597656 650 450.804688 L 650 178.226562 C 649.957031 177.929688 649.894531 177.636719 649.820312 177.34375 Z M 606.261719 167.742188 L 545.160156 167.742188 L 545.160156 124.976562 Z M 524.191406 20.96875 L 524.191406 167.742188 L 492.742188 167.742188 L 492.742188 125.804688 C 492.742188 120.015625 488.046875 115.324219 482.257812 115.324219 L 167.742188 115.324219 C 161.949219 115.324219 157.257812 120.015625 157.257812 125.804688 L 157.257812 167.742188 L 125.804688 167.742188 L 125.804688 20.96875 Z M 178.226562 167.742188 L 178.226562 136.289062 L 471.773438 136.289062 L 471.773438 167.742188 Z M 104.839844 167.742188 L 43.738281 167.742188 L 104.839844 124.976562 Z M 524.191406 608.066406 L 125.804688 608.066406 L 125.804688 461.289062 L 157.257812 461.289062 L 157.257812 503.226562 C 157.257812 509.015625 161.949219 513.710938 167.742188 513.710938 L 482.257812 513.710938 C 488.046875 513.710938 492.742188 509.015625 492.742188 503.226562 L 492.742188 461.289062 L 524.191406 461.289062 Z M 471.773438 461.289062 L 471.773438 492.742188 L 178.226562 492.742188 L 178.226562 461.289062 Z M 629.03125 440.324219 L 20.96875 440.324219 L 20.96875 188.710938 L 629.03125 188.710938 Z M 629.03125 440.324219 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 251.613281 241.128906 C 257.402344 241.128906 262.097656 236.433594 262.097656 230.644531 C 262.097656 224.855469 257.402344 220.160156 251.613281 220.160156 L 167.742188 220.160156 C 161.949219 220.160156 157.257812 224.855469 157.257812 230.644531 C 157.257812 236.433594 161.949219 241.128906 167.742188 241.128906 L 199.191406 241.128906 L 199.191406 387.902344 L 167.742188 387.902344 C 161.949219 387.902344 157.257812 392.597656 157.257812 398.386719 C 157.257812 404.175781 161.949219 408.871094 167.742188 408.871094 L 251.613281 408.871094 C 257.402344 408.871094 262.097656 404.175781 262.097656 398.386719 C 262.097656 392.597656 257.402344 387.902344 251.613281 387.902344 L 220.160156 387.902344 L 220.160156 241.128906 Z M 251.613281 241.128906 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 369.347656 220.445312 C 364.609375 219.324219 359.726562 221.605469 357.550781 225.960938 L 325 291.074219 L 292.5 225.960938 C 289.976562 220.75 283.707031 218.570312 278.492188 221.089844 C 274.839844 222.863281 272.535156 226.582031 272.578125 230.644531 L 272.578125 398.386719 C 272.578125 404.175781 277.273438 408.871094 283.0625 408.871094 C 288.851562 408.871094 293.546875 404.175781 293.546875 398.386719 L 293.546875 275.054688 L 315.617188 319.203125 C 318.707031 324.386719 325.410156 326.082031 330.59375 322.992188 C 332.152344 322.0625 333.453125 320.761719 334.382812 319.203125 L 356.449219 275.054688 L 356.449219 398.386719 C 356.449219 404.175781 361.144531 408.871094 366.933594 408.871094 C 372.726562 408.871094 377.417969 404.175781 377.417969 398.386719 L 377.417969 230.644531 C 377.417969 225.785156 374.074219 221.5625 369.347656 220.445312 Z M 369.347656 220.445312 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
<path d="M 461.289062 220.160156 L 419.355469 220.160156 C 401.984375 220.160156 387.902344 234.242188 387.902344 251.613281 L 387.902344 377.417969 C 387.902344 394.789062 401.984375 408.871094 419.355469 408.871094 L 461.289062 408.871094 C 478.660156 408.871094 492.742188 394.789062 492.742188 377.417969 L 492.742188 314.515625 C 492.742188 308.726562 488.046875 304.03125 482.257812 304.03125 L 440.320312 304.03125 C 434.53125 304.03125 429.839844 308.726562 429.839844 314.515625 C 429.839844 320.304688 434.53125 325 440.320312 325 L 471.773438 325 L 471.773438 377.417969 C 471.773438 383.210938 467.078125 387.902344 461.289062 387.902344 L 419.355469 387.902344 C 413.566406 387.902344 408.871094 383.210938 408.871094 377.417969 L 408.871094 251.613281 C 408.871094 245.824219 413.566406 241.128906 419.355469 241.128906 L 461.289062 241.128906 C 467.078125 241.128906 471.773438 245.824219 471.773438 251.613281 L 471.773438 272.582031 C 471.773438 278.371094 476.46875 283.066406 482.257812 283.066406 C 488.046875 283.066406 492.742188 278.371094 492.742188 272.582031 L 492.742188 251.613281 C 492.742188 234.242188 478.660156 220.160156 461.289062 220.160156 Z M 461.289062 220.160156 " style=" stroke:none;fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(13.72549%,12.156863%,12.54902%);fill-opacity:1;" />
</g>
</svg>



<div class="item" tabindex="1">

  <input type="text">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 650 650" width="16" height="16" class="ico ref">
    <use xlink:href="#surface" x="0">
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 438 438" width="16" height="16" class="ico ">
    <use xlink:href="#refresh" x="0">
  </svg>
</div>
```

**В обоих примерах применено SVG и иза за этого такой избыточный код**